# Copy and Rename script in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am trying to create a copy and rename files script. Here is what I have so far.

```
read COPYDIR

read DESTINATION

for file in `ls $COPYDIR`;do    
    if [ -f $COPYDIR/$file ]; then    
    cp $file $DESTINATION
    fi    
done
```

I'm trying to add a .bak extension to the files that are copied. How can I add this to the script?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to parse ls's output. You can do:

```
for file in "$COPYDIR"/*; do 
    f="${file##*/}" 
    [[ -f "$file" ]] && cp "$file" "$BAK_DEST_DIR1/$f.bak"
done
```

Comment: You need to get the basename of $file for this to work.

Comment: Thanks I just ended up posting same :)